# How to implement add a index search view on top the tableView?

Tags: iphone

I want to add the index letter on top of the UITableView when touch the index, how to do it?

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

Can't find any third party implementation of this, which is surprising (I would be happy to be proven wrong). Looks like you'll have to code it from scratch by overlaying a thin UIView subclass on top of the table view (probably best to use core graphics here to draw the outline and the letters), intercept touches on it and determine which letter they are in contact with and then send appropriate scrolling instructions to the table view using

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score -1):

Well because you have already sections you can implement when willDisplayCell method is called  to [self setTitle:[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath
```